# React update state array of objects inside array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a piece of state, invoices, that is an array of objects as such below:

```
 const [invoices, setInvoices] = useState([
  {
    id: 123,
    tag_number: "",
    item_amounts: [
      { item: "processing", amount: 159 },
      { item: "shipping", amount: 10 },
    ],
    complete: false,
    dropoff_id: "",
    customer_id: "",
    picked_up: false,
  },
  {
    id: 124,
    tag_number: "",
    item_amounts: [
      { item: "processing", amount: 169 },
      { item: "shipping", amount: 20 },
    ],
    complete: false,
    dropoff_id: "",
    customer_id: "",
    picked_up: false,
  }
]);
```

I have gathered so far that to update the value associated with a key inside one of the objects in invoices, I would need to do something like the following:

```
setInvoices(
  invoices.map((invoice) => {
    if (invoice.id === id) {
      return { ...invoice, complete: true };
    } else {
      return invoice;
    }
  })
);
```

What I'm struggling to figure out is how to update an array of objects inside one of the objects in invoices?

In particular, I'm trying to update the the `processing` object inside of `item_amounts` for an `invoice` of a particular `id`

Comment: That state's _not_ an array, you're passing two separate positional arguments to `useState`.

Comment: forgot to include the brackets - my bad

Comment: Just find the line and if it exists update, eg. `const p = invoice.item_amounts.find(f => f.item === "processing");  if (p) p.amount += 10; `

Comment: You can do the same thing as you've done for `invoices`, something like `return { ...invoice, complete: true, item_amounts: invoice.item_amounts.map((o) => ({ ...o,  amount: o.item === 'processing' ? ([the new amount]) : o.amount  }))}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this code will update the `processing` object inside of `item_amounts` for an `invoice` of  a particular `id`.

Here is the code of `setInvoice` function:

```
setInvoices(
  invoices.map((invoice) => {
    if (invoice.id === id) {
      return {
          ...invoice,
          item_amounts: invoice.item_amounts.map((item) =>
            item.item === "processing" ? { ...item, amount: newAmount } : item
          ),
        };
    } else {
      return invoice;
    }
  })
);
```

Hope to be helpful for your understanding.

Comment: It didn't even occur to me to map over the contents of item_amounts within a particular invoice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the amount value for the "processing" item inside the item_amounts array for a specific invoice ID, that means you want to update an array of objects inside one of the objects in invoices. If I'm correct, you need to perform a nested update.
Try this:

```
 const updateInvoiceItemAmount = (id, newItemAmount) => {
  setInvoices((prevInvoices) => 
    prevInvoices.map((invoice) => {
      if (invoice.id === id) {
        return {
          ...invoice,
          item_amounts: invoice.item_amounts.map((itemAmount) => {
            if (itemAmount.item === "processing") {
              return { ...itemAmount, amount: newItemAmount };
            } else {
              return itemAmount;
            }
          }),
        };
      } else {
        return invoice;
      }
    })
  );
};
```

updateInvoiceItemAmount takes an id and a new amount value (newItemAmount), uses setInvoices to update the state based on the previous state. The map function is used to iterate over each invoice in the invoices array, and for the invoice with the specified id, it updates the item_amounts array using another map function.

This ensures that you only update the amount for the "processing" item within the specified invoice.